# Firebase Remote Config doesn't work anymore

Tags: flutter, dart

I used Firebase Remote config for a while now in my flutter app.
I use it with this code:

```
  versionCheck(context) async {
    //Get Current installed version of app
    final PackageInfo info = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();
    double currentVersion = double.parse(info.version.trim().replaceAll(".", ""));

    //Get Latest version info from firebase config
    final RemoteConfig remoteConfig = await RemoteConfig.instance;

    try {
      // Using default duration to force fetching from remote server.
      await remoteConfig.fetch(expiration: const Duration(seconds: 0));
      await remoteConfig.activateFetched();
      remoteConfig.getString('force_update_current_version');
      double newVersion = double.parse(remoteConfig
          .getString('force_update_current_version')
          .trim()
          .replaceAll(".", ""));
      if (newVersion > currentVersion) {
        _showVersionDialog(context);
      }
    } on FetchThrottledException catch (exception) {
      // Fetch throttled.
      print(exception);
    } catch (exception) {
      print('Unable to fetch remote config. Cached or default values will be '
          'used');
    }
  }
```

Now, when I compile, I get these error messages:

```
lib/main.dart:977:10: Error: 'FetchThrottledException' isn't a type.
    } on FetchThrottledException catch (exception) {
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/main.dart:967:32: Error: No named parameter with the name 'expiration'.
      await remoteConfig.fetch(expiration: const Duration(seconds: 0));
                               ^^^^^^^^^^
lib/main.dart:968:26: Error: The method 'activateFetched' isn't defined for the class 'RemoteConfig'.
 - 'RemoteConfig' is from 'package:firebase_remote_config/firebase_remote_config.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_remote_config-0.10.0+5/lib/firebase_remote_config.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'activateFetched'.
      await remoteConfig.activateFetched();
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Why is it? It worked for several month and now it just stopped.

Answer (score 4):

The remote config package has gone through some breaking changes (see the [changelog](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_remote_config/changelog#070), @ 0.7.0)

Essentially, `fetch()` takes no arguments anymore. If you want to set the fetch interval, you can use

```
await remoteConfig.setConfigSettings(
  RemoteConfigSettings(
    fetchTimeout: Duration(minutes: 1),
    minimumFetchInterval: Duration(seconds: 0),
  )
);
```

Then, instead of fetching then activating, just do:

```
await remoteConfig.fetchAndActivate();
```

Finally, `FetchThrottledException` was removed - now the package will only throw `FirebaseException`.

---

Alternatively, you can roll back your version (probably to 0.6.0), but it's always good to stay up to date if possible.